# How can I check if a user with a specific name + tag exists with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a lost account that I know the name and profile picture for, however I don't know the tag. I plan to brute force all 9999 possible tags with the name, since there shouldn't be too many real accounts.
How can I check if a user with the specified name + tag exists using discord.py, and ideally display their profile picture?

I tried looking into how to turn text into a User to check for an id with User.id, and then check if it throws errors, but all questions I found only talk about users who are already in servers/the ID is known.

Comment: it is actually possible by sending multiple friend request since bots can not send friend requests you'll need to use your own user token which is against discords tos and sending multiple friend requests in a short period would lead into a account ban, so dont try it with your main account.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py or other software made to create discord bots rely on the bot being invited in servers to then establish a sort of cache of the users they met so far; just like how it will say @undefined when specifying a discord user (<@xxxx>) that you don't share a server with/are not friends with etc.
You might better scrape the possible users from a website like https://discord.id/

Comment: I've not learnt web scraping yet, but I believe it's in a python course I'm doing. Anyway, thank you for the info :)